# Where does the plus-minus come from in the quadratic formula?

Tags: quadratics, discriminant

In the formula

$$x_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$

for solving quadratic equations, where does the $\pm$ come from?

The square root already results in both a positive and negative term, is the $\pm$ not therefore extraneous?

Comment: Have you looked at the proof of the quadratic formula?

Comment: For clarity, a virtue in mathematics.

Comment: "The square root already results in both a positive and negative term" -- Usually, $\sqrt{z}$ implicitly means "the positive square root." Otherwise, $\sqrt{z}$ would not even represent a function in the usual sense (because we don't want multiple outputs for a single input).

Comment: See ["Square roots — positive and negative"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26363/139123), ["Would the answer of the square root of a square root be positive or negative?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/477162/139123), ["Is $\sqrt{64}$ considered $8$? or is it $8,-8$?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1448885/139123), ["Square root positive/negative"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2078896/139123), and various other similar questions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, the implicit meaning was not clear to me. Should the question be removed, as it is inherently a misunderstanding of notation, rather than an issue specific to the quadratic formula?

Comment: @Minos A questions which is based on misunderstanding the notation is a valid question, in my opinion. So I wouldn´t delete the question.

Comment: Actually one of my arguments to explain how we know that people define $\sqrt{x}$ as a function of $x$ (rather than something with multiple values) is that we always see $\pm$ in the solution of the quadratic equation, indicating that $\sqrt{x}$ is only one of the square roots and we need $-\sqrt{x}$ to get the other one. So I think the quadratic equation is very relevant, if only for the reason it is where we often see $\pm$ in front of a square root.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Square roots -- positive and negative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments *(and making this CW to avoid reputation gain for others' work)*, the issue is how we interpret the symbol "$\sqrt\cdot$" - is it the *function* outputting the unique nonnegative square root of a nonnegative input, or is it describing the *set of all* square roots of the input?

The standard meaning is the **former**, so e.g. $\sqrt{4}=2$. Regardless, the notation "$\pm$" only **adds** clarity to the situation.

---

Incidentally, thinking ahead to the **complex numbers**, note that while $\{x: x^2=a\}$ always makes sense there are serious problems with trying to produce a "square root *function*" in the context of $\mathbb{C}$, and more generally with exponentiation in the complex numbers in general. There are lots of posts relating to this on the site - see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3855767/theres-a-deeper-concept-behind-this-fake-proof/3855787#3855787).

Answer (score 1):

What about completing squares?
\begin{align*}
ax^{2} + bx + c & = a\left(x^{2} + \frac{bx}{a}\right) + c\\\\
& = a\left(x^{2} + \frac{bx}{a} + \frac{b^{2}}{4a^{2}}\right) + c - \frac{b^{2}}{4a}\\\\
& = a\left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^{2} + \frac{4ac - b^{2}}{4a}
\end{align*}
Hence we deduce that
\begin{align*}
ax^{2} + bx + c = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow a\left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^{2} + \frac{4ac - b^{2}}{4a} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^{2} = \frac{b^{2} - 4ac}{4a^{2}}\\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}{2a} 
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Given a general quadratic
\begin{eqnarray*}
ax^2+bx+c=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply through by $4a$, add $b^2$ & this will allow us to "complete the square"
\begin{eqnarray*}
4a^2x^2+4abx+b^2 &=& b^2-4ac\\
(2ax+b)^2 &=& b^2-4ac.\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now take the square root, this is where the plus-minus comes from ...